# Is there a good reference for what basic operations cost in recent versions of .NET?

Tags: .net, performance, clr

A very long time ago (2003) the CLR Performance Team published an article authored by Jan Grey called "[Writing Faster Managed Code: Know What Things Cost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx)".  In the ten years since this was written .NET has had many more basic operations added; and I'm sure the performance of many of the basic operations referenced in the article have changed since the original release of the CLR.

Is there a good reference out there that has updated performance measurement for basic operations for more recent versions of the CLR?

Comment: Nice question but I suppose it's little bit off-topic (_"...Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite **offf-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam..."_).

Comment: @Adriano Is there a better stack exchange site for these sorts of questions?

Comment: Chuu i found this question, where it seems like at least be 2009, 4 years ago but 6 years from the origial post, there was no updated version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719449/is-there-an-updated-version-of-writing-faster-managed-code-know-what-things-co

Comment: Would I rather tune an application by (possibly out of date information) or by running the application in a profiler? Hmm. Tricky choice. For about 453 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

The most up-to-date reference from the CLR team is the [MeasureIt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2009/02/06/measureit-update-tool-for-doing-microbenchmarks.aspx) tool and the MSDN magazine articles ([part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500596.aspx), [part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507639.aspx)) that went along with it. MeasureIt doesn't have the same set of tests that Jan's article has, but it ships with source code so you can easily edit it to add additional tests. `MeasureIt.exe /edit` will extract the source code for you. Just `MeasureIt.exe` will run a standard set of tests and open the results.

Also, most of the higher-level concepts in Jan's article are still relevant and accurate. It's just that the numbers are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

As one rather sarcastic comment noted, this information is largely made obsolete by the rise of quality, free/affordable profiling tools. The best way to address performance at this level is to write code in a way that is comfortable and maintainable, and then let a profiler tell you where things are slow.